# Change Field name in elasticsearch response

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I need to change field names in elastic search response (ex. change "title" to "header"). i want to avoid parsing the Json response which take much time.
is there any way to do that?

Comment: What client technology are you using, Java? Can you show the bit of code where you make the request and get your response?

Comment: yes. i am using the java API for elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more of your use case and why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid this might not be available in elasticsearch. you might have to parse the response. consider

Aliasing

One of the things introduced in Apache Solr 4.0 and not available in ElasticSearch right now is the ability to transform result documents. First of all Solr allows you to alias returned fields, so for example you can return field price_usd or price_eur as price depending on your needs. The second thing is the ability to return values returned by functions as a (pseudo) field in the result (or fields). Solr also has the ability to return fields which start with a given prefix (for example all fields starting with price). Apart from the ability to get a function value as a field added to matched documents on the fly other functionalities are not ground breaking, though they can be handy in some cases.

from http://blog.sematext.com/2012/10/01/solr-vs-elasticsearch-part-3-searching/